# Visualizar tiempo correctamente en vertical axis en microsoft report builder

Tags: sql, report, gráficas, rdlc

mi problema es que tengo una serie de reportes los cuáles tienen sus respectivas gráficas, mi problema es que intento hacer que en el eje vertical o Y, se muestre el tiempo correctamente.

A lo que me refiero es que el tiempo lo muestra en intervalos de 20-40-60-80, he intentado bastantes cosas de formas aleatorias pero lo máximo que he logrado es que se muestre 00:00:00 el problema es que cuando pasa del 00:00:60 en vez de pasar a minutos, muestra como 00:00:80 y ya no tengo ni idea que probar para arreglarlo, adjunto imagen de como muestra la grafica.

[image: Gráfica]

Lo que he intentado es cambiar el formato del Axis con distintos formatos de tiempo, intente aplicar algunas expresiones que mencionan los foros de ayuda de Report Builder pero igual no me funcionaron.

Intente también agregar los !fields del eje X para ver si lograba con eso modificar los valores que se mostraban en el eje Y pero tampoco funciono.

Comment: Hola WolfangTK, bienvenido, para poder ayudarte, necesitamos ver tu código y los mensajes de error (si es que los recibes) en formato texto, y que nos expliques en que falla, mira Cómo preguntar para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada. aprovecha y haz el recorrido de Bienvenida para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!